# getCreators() Type Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I wrote the following function to try to get the user that created the gCal event.

To test this I created an event on calendar and tried to run the script. When the script executes it gets error: "TypeError: Cannot find function getCreators in object CalendarEvent. (line 68, file "Code")".

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm fairly certain getCreators() is a function in object CalendarEvent (Ref:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getCreators())

```
function getuser(instr) {
  var today = new Date();
  var scriptProperties=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var instrcal= scriptProperties.getProperty(instr);
  var event=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(instrcal).getEventsForDay(today);
  if (event<1) {
    var user= 'None'
    }
  else if (event>1) {
    var user= 'Multiple Users'
    }
  else {
    var user= event.getCreators()
    }
  return user
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getEventsForDay` [returns an array of CalendarEvent objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventsForDay(Date)), all events for that day, even if it is just one.
You'll need to go through the events to find the one you want and then call `getCreators()`.

You can verify this by using

```
var event=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(instrcal).getEventsForDay(today)[0];
```

Here the call will work.

Comment: Did not realize it would still return an array if there is a single value. That solved it! Thank you!

Comment: You have to check with `event.length` before to try to get the first element `event[0]`

Comment: In an unsupervised environment yes, here we knew OP had at least one event as they created it themselves, so I omitted it for brevity

Answer (score 0):

The method [getEventsForDay(date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventsForDay(Date)) gets an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) all events that occur on a given day.

Check that you are doing: `event < 1` instead of `event.length < 1`.

Code:

```
function getuser(instr) {
    var today = new Date(),
        scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
        instrcal = scriptProperties.getProperty(instr),
        events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(instrcal).getEventsForDay(today),
        user = 'None';

    if (events.length === 1) {
        user = events[0].getCreators();
    } else if (events.length > 1) {
        user = 'Multiple Users';
    }

    return user;
}
```